# How do I stop the FLOAT (without extra markup)?

Tags: css, css-float, nav

**Question**:
How do I get what comes after my `NAV` to not float?

**Preface:**
I am putting together a little reusable *progress-tracker* module to be plugged into some tools being built for internal use from within our firewall.
While cross-browser compatibility is nice, we only ***need*** to code against Chrome and FireFox. Those are the only browsers officially supported by our tech team.
Also, ANY and ALL suggestions for improvement are always welcome.

**The Challenge:** FLOATS!!
In order for the arrows to show correctly and behave intuitively, I had to *right* float the `li`'s. 
 (by *"had"*, I mean *"couldn't think of a better way"* :)

In order to prevent the whole `nav` from floating to the right, I had to *left* float that.
Now, whatever comes after the nav is right up there in-line with it.

**Note:**
You can also see and play with the code [**here on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mOrloff/G6J6P/).

**Code:**
HTML:

```
<nav id="progress_tracker">
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Grab a beer</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Work a little more</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class="current">Take a Nap</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class="complete">Work like a dog</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class="complete">Grab a coffee</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    float: left;
}
nav#progress_tracker {
    padding: 0.25em;
    background-color: #1a3340;
    border-radius: 1.75em;
}
nav ul li:last-child{                       /* Remember. We are floating right, so last is furthest left */
    margin-left: -1.7em;
}
nav ul{
    list-style-type: none; 
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #777;
    background-color: DDD;
    padding-top: 0.75em;                    /* top/btm padding need to be half of line-height */
    padding-bottom: 0.75em;                 /* top/btm padding need to be half of line-height */
    padding-left: 2em;                      /* left padding */
    padding-right: 1em;                     /* right padding is (left-padding - depth-of-arrow (see below) */
    line-height: 1.5em;                     /* line-height needs to be double top/btm padding */
}
nav ul li a:after{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -1em;                            /* depth of offset (equal to depth of arrow) */
    border-left: 1em solid #d9d9d9;         /* depth of arrow (equal to depth of offset) */
    border-top: 1.5em inset transparent;    /* border thickness needs to match line-height */
    border-bottom: 1.5em inset transparent; /* border thickness needs to match line-height */
    content: "";                            /* required to make all of this work */
}
nav ul li a:visited{
    color: #888888;
}

nav ul li a.current{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
    background-color: #FFBB00;
}
nav ul li a.current:after{
    border-left: 1em solid #FFBF00;         /* depth of arrow (equal to depth of offset) */
}

nav ul li a.complete{
    color: #666;
    background-color: #FFFFEE;
}
nav ul li a.complete:after{
    border-left: 1em solid #FFFFEF;         /* depth of arrow (equal to depth of offset) */
}

nav ul li:last-child a{                    /* Remember. We are floating right, so last is furthest left */
    border-top-left-radius: 1.45em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1.45em;
}
nav ul li:first-child a{                    /* Remember. We are floating right, so first is furthest rt */
    border-top-right-radius: 1.45em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1.45em;
}
nav ul li:first-child a:after{
    border: none;
}
```

Thanks-a-bunch.

Comment: Ahaaa refreshing post, feels like reading a science journal, experiment - conclusion etc...and btw answer is pretty simple, just clear your floats :p `clear: both;`tadaa.. `100/100` for me..vuhooo

Comment: Thanks .. for the compliment AND the suggestion. I did try `clear: both;`, but wasn't getting the desired results because I wasn't sure where _exactly_ I should be doing my clearing :) ... if you have any suggestions I could add to my toolbox, I'd be thrilled to hear them. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you wanted to keep the markup the same, but you had an issue with using `display:inline-block;` and having space between the `li` elements. Here's a working version without the `float` mess ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/G6J6P/19/)). It has `:before` and `:after`, each acting as half of the *preceding* arrow. I've added a `:hover` style so you can test the hovering and see how to style it yourself.

***Note:** This does not look as pretty when wrapped.*

### HTML

```
<nav id="progress_tracker">
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#' class="complete">Grab a coffee</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href='#'>Work like a dog</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href='#' class="complete">Take a Nap</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href='#' class="current">Work a little more</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href='#'>Grab a beer</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p>Some random text</p>
```

### New CSS

```css
a:hover,
a:hover:before,
a:hover:after {
    background:lime !important;
}
nav#progress_tracker {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0.25em;
    background-color: #1a3340;
    border-radius: 1.75em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #777;
    background: #1A3340;
    padding-top: 0.75em;                    /* top/btm padding need to be half of line-height */
    padding-bottom: 0.75em;                 /* top/btm padding need to be half of line-height */
    padding-left: 1em;                      /* left padding */
    padding-right: 1.5em;                   /* right padding is (left-padding + 1/2 depth-of-arrow (see below) */
    line-height: 1.5em;                     /* line-height needs to be double top/btm padding */
}
nav ul li a:before,
nav ul li a:after {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: "";                            /* required to make all of this work */
    background: #1A3340;
}
nav ul li a:before{
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(33deg) translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: skewX(33deg) translate(-50%);
    transform: skewX(33deg) translate(-50%);
}
nav ul li a:after{
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-33deg) translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: skewX(-33deg) translate(-50%);
    transform: skewX(-33deg) translate(-50%);
}
nav ul li a:visited{
    color: #888888;
}

/* .current styles */
nav ul li a.current{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
    background-color: #FFBB00;
}
nav ul li a.current:before,
nav ul li a.current:after{
    background: #FFBF00;
}

/* .complete styles */
nav ul li a.complete{
    color: #666;
    background-color: #FFFFEE;
}
nav ul li a.complete:before,
nav ul li a.complete:after{
    background: #FFFFEF;
}

/* First/last fixes */
nav ul li:first-child a {
    border-top-left-radius: 1.45em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1.45em;
}
nav ul li:last-child a {
    border-top-right-radius: 1.45em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1.45em;
}
nav ul li:first-child a:before,
nav ul li:first-child a:after{
    background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I like this solutions ... a alot ... the one hangup is the fact that the arrow does not behave intuitively. When a user clicks on the arrow portion of one of the segments, where they are taken and where they expect to be taken are two different things :) If there's a way to solve that one hurdle, this would be a GREAT option.

Comment: @mOrloff I've updated my answer with a new technique that should act the way you're expecting. The one downside is it doesn't look great when it wraps (but either did the original, so I'm assuming that's okay). You may notice the background showing through under the arrows at first on jsFiddle--in that case, just resize the frame, and it'll fix the subpixel rouding issue.

Comment: That's pretty sweet! I've never encountered functional commenting brackets like that. More info would be appreciated if you've got it. While they are _technically_ extra markup, that doesn't bother me much. When I get a chance, I'm going to refactor this into my little plugin. Thanks-a-bunch.

Comment: @mOrloff The comments are there to get rid of extra whitespace, which actually affect the layout (due to `display:inline-block;`). Another way around this is to simply not have any whitespace between the tags.

Comment: @mOrloff I'm assuming you're referring to the hover rule? I've added that back :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems a little kludgey, but without adding markup, you could set a css style on p elements as such:

```
p {
    clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G6J6P/2/

If you're okay with markup, instead I would just do:

```
<br style="clear:both;" />
```

after your nav.

Comment: I should have clarified that I don't consider extra markup Toxic, I just prefer to stay away from it whenever practical :) Thanks

Comment: I certainly understand the desire to keep it clean; judging from your question, you're methodical and maybe OCD ;)  Regardless, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Apply the css style

```
clear: both;
```

to the next element. This will prevent whatever it is from nestling itself beside your floated `nav`.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there is a consensus between you and @stlrick.